# Отслеживание ошибки после стороннего скрипта

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Есть сторонний скрипт(виджет), подключаемый через `тег script`, я хотел бы после загрузки, если в скрипте возникает ошибка, то показывать в верстке компонент с текстом, о том, что произошла ошибка. Как примерно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Это сильно зависит от того, какую ошибку вы ожидаете. Можно попробовать через событие [onError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event) на windows:

```js
window.addEventListener('error', e => console.log(e.message));

let script = document.createElement('script');
document.body.appendChild(script);
script.src = 'data:text/javascript;base64,' + btoa('aler("Hello world")');
```

Это сработает для каких-то случаев.

Но если ошибка будет поинтереснее (например виджет не сможет что-нибудь загрузить и просто остановится), то вы сможете понять, что произошла ошибка только сравнив полученный результат с ожидаемым. Например вы можете проверить, что виджет создал какие-то ключевые элементы на странице после загрузки скрипта. Дайте ему немного времени и поищите элементы на странице.

В любом случае, гарантировать, что сторонний код работает правильно вы не можете. Виджет может выглядеть отлично, но при нажатии на кнопку падать.